# Regex to Match URL with a Specific Query Param (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need to match a set of URLs and they all must contain a specific query param

**(type=VCL)**

So far I have `/http:\/\/myhost:8080\/organization\/(\d*)\/mediaResource?.*$/`

Which matches urls formed like `http://myhost:8080/organizaton/5/mediaResource?anyParam(s)` but I need to only get matches if the the URL contains the query param type=VCL

like:  `http://myhost:8080/organization/5/mediaResource?someParam=foo&type=VCL`

Can someone help with the last part of the regex to get only URLs that contain the query param I care about?

Comment: check this:https://regex101.com/r/lO1eS5/1 this very simpe the expression need to be type=VCL and that it's unless i didn't understand what you looking for...

Comment: i would use a queryString parser instead of a regexp, which is fragile when considering all the forms of entity encoding that are legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
http:\/\/myhost:8080\/organization\/(\d*)\/mediaResource\?\S*\btype=VCL\b\S*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ9qV9/1)

I only added a slash before the `?` so that it was matched literally, added `\S*` matching 0 or more non-whitespace symbols, and `\btype=VCL\b` so that only those URLs that have this param are matched.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend using a URI parser for this - it's easier to read and more maintainable and someone has done the work of testing the constituent regexes.

I've had good success with this lightweight one:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

Comment: This is for some inline routing in some mocking for Protractor, do you think your suggestion would work for that?

Comment: I don't see why not. If anything, having a URI parsed into an easily manipulable structure  by long-tested code should make this easier. For instance it's trivial to change your logic to use some other query param, or an anchor tag or the host or some combination. Whereas you might have a hard time remembering exactly how your custom, single param regex works, let alone reliably modifying it, a month from now.